# Bound of sample mean of exponential distribution using Chbyshev's inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X_{1}, \cdots, X_{n}$ be independent. Suppose they have exponential distribution with variance $4$. I want to bound $P(\frac{X_{1}+\cdots+X_{n}}{n} > 1.5)$ by using Chebyshev's inequality.

My attempt:

Let $X=\frac{X_{1}+\cdots+X_{n}}{n}$.

Since $\text{Exp}(\lambda) = \text{gamma}(1,\lambda)$, I have $X_{1} + \cdots + X_{n} \sim \text{gamma}(n,\lambda)$

So $X = \frac{X_{1}+\cdots+X_{n}}{n} \sim \text{gamma}(n,n\lambda)$.

From mean and variance of gamma distribution, I get  $\text{E}X = 1/\lambda = 2, \text{Var}(X) = 1/(n\lambda^2) = 4/n$ (Here, I use $\lambda = 2$ as given in problem)

But then, how can I apply Chebyshev's inequality to $X$? $P(X>1.5) = P(X-2 > -0.5)$ holds, but it's not of the form $P(\lvert X-\mu \rvert > k)$. So I wonder how I can apply Chebyshev's inequality to get desired.